# Split and save dataframe into several csv files based on the number of rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has `1000` columns and `24729` rows.
I need to save it as several csv files (for example 10) split based on the number of rows.

I have checked many questions and most of them are for data.frames that can be split using levels of a factor. I could not find any examples that can be done based on number of rows.

I did a number of trials but none of them worked.

How would you save `diamonds` as 10 csv files split based on the number of rows?

```
library(ggplot)
df = diamonds
```

Comment: You're almost there. Create your own variable that will designate a group for ten rows at a time. For example `rep(1:100, each = 10)` should give you 100 groups, each holding 10 entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following writes 10 csv's to your working directory:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = diamonds

SPLITS <- 10
tmp <- sort(rep(seq_len(SPLITS), length.out = nrow(df)))
iwalk(split(df, tmp), ~write_csv(.x, str_c(str_c(getwd(), "/", .y, ".CSV"))))
```